# How to root Redmi 4X?

Tags: rooting, twrp, lineageos, xiaomi, redmi

I wish to install [TWRP](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomiredmi4x.html), [LineageOS](https://download.lineageos.org/santoni) and [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads) on a Redmi 4X I have to replace the stock ROM.

I installed ArrowOS on a Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus very recently and it went very smoothly.

However searching around online, unlocking Redmi phones seem to be a real pain.

While [this link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-redmi-4x-root.3811440/) tells how to root it and install TWRP(the easy part) it doesn't talk about the part of unlocking the phone's bootloader in the first place.
[This link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unofficial-unlock-bootloader-redmi-4x.4150597/) leads nowhere.

[This link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/couldnt-unlock-bootloader.3978213/) is pretty irrelevant because I don't have a Windows PC. Any tips to do this with Arch Linux??

I couldn't really make sense of [this rather long and intimidating thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bootloader-unlock-all-variants-the-only-thing-you-need-to-read.3565459/) though it seems to be the most promising one.

I couldn't make any sense of the other google results and they lead me nowhere.

I'm still quite a noob with Android and so would appreciate any help I get.

Comment: [VirtualBox platform package + Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) // [Windows ISO](http://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+7+Professional+x64+sp1+iso) // [miflash unlock tool](https://en.miui.com/unlock/download_en.html)

Comment: [unlocking](https://c.mi.com/thread-2262302-1-0.html) requires mi account and activated sim card bonded to device for 15 days. after this period unlocking works with miflash unlock tool. [Francesco Tescari](https://www.xda-developers.com/xiaomitool-windows-mod-xiaomi-smartphone) has reverse engineered miflash unlock and provides unofficial linux alternative [MiUnlockTool.sh](https://miui.blog/any-devices/mi-unlock-tool-mac-linux) (requires java). There is also another linux build of unofficial [XiaoMiTool V2](https://github.com/francescotescari/XMT/releases) which provides bootloader unlocking

Comment: @alecxs, I installed xiaomitool-v2 (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xiaomitool-v2/)/ available in the arch user repository. But when I open it, it is apparently still in beta. So Will it be safe to use this tool? Can it make the phone COMPLETELY bricked?

Comment: Why do I need to keep an active sim in the phone? Can't it be done without the sim?

Comment: I just don't get how a VM running windows 10 can safely root a phone. Won't I get problems with drivers and such?

Comment: If it works in a VM, I'll do it in a VM, though I can't give more than 4 gb ram to the windows VM. I'll proceed in a VM if I can get any assurance about reliability from you since it is my mother's only phone and bricking it will be a complete nightmare.

Comment: Also should I download the 64-bit version of the Windows 10 ISO? Or is the 32 bit ISO sufficient? The only purpose I want it for is the unlocking of this device.

Comment: please consider deleting your comments if you think they are no longer relevant. you might include useful info/links in the answer below instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I successfully rooted my device and installed lineageos in it today.

I created an mi account(couple days back) witj my phone number, made a windows vm and used an [unofficial tool] [https://kkworld.in/unlock-mi-bootloader-without-waiting-time/] to unlock the bootloader.

Initially getting my vm to recognise connected usb devices was an issue but I found a [superuser solution][https://superuser.com/a/1295185] and then rebooting.

You can check if usb devices are working without turning on a vm. I've posted it [here][https://github.com/arch-linux-enthusiast/android-rooting/commit/3924a65d6681a4efd9fdfd2931b82d47321e3556]. Yep I've also made a github account (with very little substantial content since I barely know anything).

I didn't have any waiting time for the unlocking to happen, but keep in mind this tool is possibly modded as far as I know. If you have the patience, use the official tool and wait it out.

Thanks for all the support, I couldn't have done it without your help, @alecxs!!!